# Custom systemd service won't start automatically

Tags: hard-drive, systemd

I wrote a script and a service to power down my external Seagate drive on shutdown. It worked the first time but when I restart my computer it won't activate. I always have to start it manually before shutdown, which defeats the purpose. Maybe someone here can help me making the service working in a way that always when I shutdown the computer it will also turn of the drive.

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh

disk_uuid="MY-UUID-PLACEHOLDER"

udisksctl unmount -b /dev/disk/by-uuid/${disk_uuid} 
udisksctl power-off -b /dev/disk/by-uuid/${disk_uuid}

exit 0
```

Service file:

```
[Unit] 
Description=Shut down external disks
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target kexec.target halt.target

[Service] 
Type=oneshot ExecStart=/usr/sbin/power-off-disk.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install] 
WantedBy=halt.target kexec.target reboot.target shutdown.target
```

Logs from journalctl -u:

```
Feb 22 11:53:50 ace-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Shut down external disks...
Feb 22 11:53:50 ace-desktop power-off-disk.sh[9810]: Error connecting to the udisks daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Feb 22 11:53:50 ace-desktop power-off-disk.sh[9880]: Error connecting to the udisks daemon: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.UDisks2: Transaction for udisks2.service/start is destructive (dev-sdb1.swap has 'stop' job queued, but 'start' is included in transaction).
Feb 22 11:53:50 ace-desktop systemd[1]: power-off-disk.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 22 11:53:50 ace-desktop systemd[1]: Finished Shut down external disks.
```

So I now edited my Service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Shut down external disks
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=udisks2.service shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/power-off-disk.sh
RemainAfterExit=no

[Install]
WantedBy=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target
```

It changes nothing though.

> systemctl start power-off-disk

works, when activated manually, but not on shutdown.
Help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Hello,

thank you for your answer. Yes, I enabled the service. I can also manually start it, which turns off the Drive but it won't start on shutdown, reboot or anything else.

Comment: Would it maybe help if I replaced the "Before=" With "Before=umount.target" ?